# Robotstxt Google Searchresults

Tags: sitemap, google-search, robots.txt

My search results index all the sites on Google. I only want to index the main page and not the /nl/, /en/ and /fr/ 
How can I prevent this in my robots.txt?

I used

```
Disallow: /nl/
Disallow: /fr/
Disallow: /en/
```

But what with my sitemap with the URL www.eikhoeve.be/nl/sitemap.xml how can I allow this one for my Google Webmaster Tools?

[My website](http://www.eikhoeve.be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Allow` keyword to give access to a URL in a Disallowed directory.

```
Allow: /nl/sitemap.xml
Disallow: /nl/
```

Comment: I would swap these two lines. What you've got will work fine on Google and Bing, but some other crawlers have different precedence rules. Putting the Allow first maximizes the odds it will be understood.